# Python : ValueError: Shapes (3, 1) and (512, 3) are incompatible during the training of a Transformer model

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, valueerror, sentence-transformers

I'm trying to build a model from a "classic" dataset.
This dataset has 2 columns :

- The "text" column which contains some text extracted from pdf documents
- the "label" column : it is the label associated to the extracted text.

I'm trying to build NLP model using the "transformers" library but when
the code execute the training part, the following error is raising :

**

```
Une exception s'est produite : ValueError
in user code:

File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_tf_utils.py", line 909, in train_step
    loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
    loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 141, in __call__
    losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 245, in call  **
    return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1790, in categorical_crossentropy
    y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
File "C:\Users\lione\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5083, in categorical_crossentropy
    target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

ValueError: Shapes (3, 1) and (512, 3) are incompatible
  
  File"C:\Users\lione\AppData\Local\Temp
 \__autograph_generated_fileacj4 
 qa7l.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
 retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), 
(ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)

  During handling of the above exception, another exception 
  occurred:

  

  File"C:\Users\lione\OneDrive\Bureau\Lionel\LDK_360\Projets
 \Novasecur\Tests\Transformers.py", line 92, in <module>
  model.fit(dataset,epochs=3)
```

My code :

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import DataCollatorWithPadding
from transformers import create_optimizer
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import io
import nltk
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical 

df = pd.read_excel('transformers.xlsx')


print(df.head())


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")
X = list(df['text'])
train_encodings = tokenizer(X, truncation=True, padding=True)


y =list(df['label'])

y = tf.cast(y,tf.int32)

y = to_categorical(y, 3)

y = tf.cast(y,tf.int32)


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(train_encodings),y))

model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base- 
uncased", num_labels=3)

batch_size = 16
num_epochs = 5
batches_per_epoch = len(dataset) // batch_size
total_train_steps = int(batches_per_epoch * num_epochs)
optimizer, schedule = create_optimizer(init_lr=2e-5, num_warmup_steps=0, 
num_train_steps=total_train_steps)

# 

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])


# Train the model
model.fit(dataset,epochs=3)
```

You can execute this code with the **transformers.xlsx** file you can download here :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16tPffyOXd6i1R2ohNUO3BhcSkinNtOIn/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117798974480569779583&rtpof=true&sd=true

So far, I tried to change the loss function to **sparse_categorical_crossentropy**
but without success...

Can you help me to fix this error/bug ?

Regards,

Lionel

Comment: Can you provide a complete stack trace? It would help pinpoint where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Also, please provide all the import statements required for your code to work by simple cut and pasting.

Comment: @joanis , I updated the question with the required informations...